# How to compile sass / scss without creating map files

Tags: css, command-line, compilation, sass

I went looking for this answer and noticed it is not yet on Stack Overflow.  So I hope to share this knowledge for anyone in need.

**Situation:**

In the command line: compiling compressed SASS files from the scss folder into the css folder.

`sass --watch scss:css --style compressed`

This creates css files, but it also creates .map files as well.

**Question:**

So how do I stop these .map files from being created?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Answer:**

Add `--sourcemap=none` to your command.

So it will look like:

`sass --watch scss:css --style compressed --sourcemap=none`

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but what does it impact on SASS?

Comment: @William, do you mean what impact do the map files have?

Comment: Yes, and why did you wanted to remove those files in the first place. Id like to know more about SASS

Comment: I remove them because there are so many and they cause conflicts with git.  Here is some more information about what they do: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, see sh78's answer below. (I think you should mention that in your answer too)

Answer (score 10):

**Update for 2019**

Running `--sourcemap-none` on the latest version of `sass` (1.21.0) returns `Could not find an option named "sourcemap".`

The new flag is `--no-source-map`.

```
━━━ Source Maps ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
--[no-]source-map          Whether to generate source maps.
                           (defaults to on)

--source-map-urls          How to link from source maps to source files.
                           [relative (default), absolute]

--[no-]embed-sources       Embed source file contents in source maps.
--[no-]embed-source-map    Embed source map contents in CSS.
```

Also, sass is one of the many CLI programs with built-in help output. Running `sass` without any arguments shows usage instruction and various flags, like this one.

Answer (score 4):

Updated command:

```
sass -w input.scss output.css --style compressed --no-source-map
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Update, now the proper command to avoid creating a map file is:

```
--no-source-map
```